# c# windows form application on windows server

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am building a win form application in c# which will be installed on windows server 2008. All  users that will be using this application connects with their username and password using remote desktop connection. What happens if two or more users opens this application? Will it work correctly for all user? or it become race condition ( `who gets first wins? :)` ) what do I need to do to make it work correctly for all users? maybe I need to create `System.Net.Sockets` or something else?

**UPDATED:**

Code to select data from table and then update it:

```
DuomenysDataSet ds; //dataset which was created when I create a database on visual studio
public static string ID { get; set; }
private void FillDataGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT PirminiaiNuo,PirminiaiIki,Ikainis,MenesinisMokestis,Metine FROM \"" + ID + "\"", DBConnection);
            ds = database.FillData(command, "Ikainiai"); // "Ikainiai" = DataSet table name

            IkainiaiView.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "PirminiaiNuo";
            IkainiaiView.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "PirminiaiIki";
            IkainiaiView.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Ikainis";
            IkainiaiView.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "MenesinisMokestis";
            IkainiaiView.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "Metine";
            IkainiaiView.Enabled = false;
            IkainiaiView.DataSource = ds.Tables[a];
            IkainiaiView.Enabled = true;

        }
```

To update table I pass same SqlCommand and table name to the database class method `updateTable` code below:

```
public void updateDatabase(SqlCommand command, string tableName)
    {

        sql = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        sql.SelectCommand = command;
        sql.SelectCommand.Connection = Connection();
        SqlCommandBuilder c = new SqlCommandBuilder(sql); // not sure if this is necessary 

        sql.Update(ds.Tables[tableName]);
    }
```

Code to create a new table: here ID is the `AutoIncrement` id from different table (primary key) this is why it is not a parameter.

```
public static string ID { get; set; }
private void Kainininkas_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * INTO \"" + ID + "\" FROM IkainiuSablonasPilnas", DBConnection);
     try
     {
          DBConnection.Open();
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
          DBConnection.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          TopMostMessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

To insert new rows to the table i use this code:

```
DBConnection = database.Connection();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Imones (Imone,Adresas,ImonesKodas,PVMKodas,Vykdytojas,Musu,SutartiesNr,SutartiesData,Sutartis,Active,Buhalteris) VALUES (@Imone,@adresas,@ImonesKodas,@PVMKodas,@Vykdytojas,'',@SutartiesNR, @SutartiesData,@Sutartis,@Active,@Buhalteris);", DBConnection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imone", textBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adresas", textBox2.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImonesKodas", UzsakovasImonesKodasText.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PVMKodas", textBox4.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vykdytojas", ImoniuSarasasCmb.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutartiesNR", textBox3.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SutartiesData", dateTimePicker1.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@Sutartis", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = buff;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", aktyvi);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Buhalteris", comboBox1.Text);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: It entirely depends on what your application does. Sockets aren't magically going to solve an unspoken problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster This application is for creating PDF files from the sql database. Users select what items they want and app generates pdf files accordingly. User also can modify data inside sql database. So basically this app has a lot of sql command and navigation between different forms.

Comment: As long as the app isn;t locking physical resources (files) while another copy tries to use them, you can open/use multiple copies of your winforms app at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the app isn;t locking physical resources (files) while another copy tries to use them, you can open/use multiple copies of your winforms app at the same time.

**EDIT**

As an extra note, thanks to CodeCaster, if you implement a file based db access routine, that may lock the file when accessing the DB file, you could run into issues. If you use a service level DB implementation, like SQL Express, then there should not be any issues with running multiple copies of the app.

As a last note, its perfectly normal for an application to run as multiple copies on the same Application server. Think about, Ms Word, Exel, Outlook, Adobe Reader, Windows Explorer...

Just make sure you take the above points into account.

Comment: just to be sure files resources (files) you describe is c# class files or something like text files?

Comment: Text files/pdf files, etc... anything that cna be "locked" by the system. I.e. App copy 1 and app copy 2 cant write to "c:\123.pdf" at the same time

Comment: So using savefiledialog is not the option if for eg different user save file on their desktop using same file name?

Comment: It comes down to design. Have each app "save" to teh user profile location, and not to lets say, the sme location on the root of c:... This way, each user operates in his own "hard drive space" inside his user profile.

Comment: OP stated _"User also can modify data inside sql database"_. Depending on how this is implemented, this _can_ cause trouble.

Comment: OK I agree, but this is becoming a very broad scenario. If it is a pretty normal implementation... it should be fine, but I will udpate my answer none the less. Thanks

Comment: Yes it is broad, which makes it a not so good question. Using SQL Server does not prevent you from threading issues. Multiple users can modify the same record at the same time, causing changes to be overwritten and so on.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am using SQL databse for service-based data not sure if this is good or no. To update values inside database I use `SqlCommand.Update` method. All this is managed from a Database class that i have created. I have updated my original question with code for you to look at update, insert and create commands. Could you look at them and tell your opinion? Thanks!

Comment: @CodeCaster to prevent `Multiple users can modify the same record at the same time, causing changes to be overwritten` should I use locks?

Comment: @EimantasBaigys I believe this is venturing off-topic. We are describing and discussing hypothetical scenarios, that exist in normal every software. This actually has nothing to-do with running the same application multiple times on an applications server... This is basic distributed application design... You have got the necessary facts. I say, build your software, at least a proof of concept, and handle issues when they arrive. It's good to plan, but then, you must be working with a plan.. at this stage, I see no plan... yet :-)